# IO error after PSU change

Tags: boot, gnome, hard-drive

I have just changed my PSU with better one...
Plugged cables as same (and i unplug DVD)

It works OK... But stuck here. Then blank screen...

[image]

/etc/init.d/rc: 121: /etc/init.d/rc: /etc/rc2.d/S20kerneloops: Input/output error

[image: second]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NiKpX.jpg

Comment: Looks like your drive is broke.  Boot the live cd, open the disks utility, and check the SMART health of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If its for that 4870 you're sporting in your sig, try plugging the dvi cable into the other dvi port on the back of the card. The signal sometimes goes from one port to the other when uninstalling/reinstalling card and/or drivers. Other than that, check your pci-e power cables, make sure they are securely plugged in. Good luck.

Comment: Win7 also installed in same HDD and works without problem.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MZLt0EU.jpg?1    This screen when i try to boot on safe mode